# C# arguments values in methods

Tags: c#

If I write `a = a +115` my `MessageBox` will return 215 but if write like `a=115;` it will display 115.

Why is that?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int c=100;
    MessageBox.Show(Count(c).ToString());
}

public int Count(int a)
{
    a=115;
    return a;
}
```

Comment: Why should that happen? What don't you understand?

Comment: little secret for you... 100 + 115 **IS** 215!

Comment: How come a gets the value of c when i write a = a + 115?

Comment: @Benny Because your passing `c` as the first parameter of `Count`. First parameter of `Count` is called `a`.

Comment: Your `Count` function will always return 115. Are you sure that's what you intended?

Comment: @Benny: because `a` is already 100, as passed in to the function using the value of `c`

Comment: @YaqubAhmad: A "Why" question... `"Why is that?"`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: What was that David? You need to speak up a little, my hearing isn't what it used to be

Comment: I suspect this is a by reference vs by value question. However, the wording is very unclear, made worse by the `Count` function probably containing a typo.

Comment: I strongly recommend you read some basic C# tutorials before asking questions like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are three versions of your code to demonstrate what is going on, and what I think you're really asking:

Original:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Set c to 100
    int c=100;

    // Print the result of Count, which (see below) is ALWAYS 115.
    MessageBox.Show(Count(c).ToString());
}

public int Count(int a)
{
    // Set a to 115 (there is no add here, I think this is a typo)
    a=115;
    // Return a, which is ALWAYS 115.
    return a;
}
```

What I think you meant:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Set c to 100
    int c=100;

    // Print the result of Count, which will be 215.
    MessageBox.Show(Count(c).ToString());
}

public int Count(int a)
{
    // Add 115 to a.
    a+=115;

    // Return the result (if a == 100, this will return 215)
    return a;
}
```

What I think you're getting at:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Set c to 100
    int c=100;

    // Call the count function, passing in a reference for c.
    Count(ref c);

    // Print the value of c. This will be 215 because the Count function set c to a new value.
    MessageBox.Show(c.ToString());
}

public void Count(ref int a)
{
    a+=115;
}
```

In this last case, I changed the function to `public void Count(ref int a)`. The `ref` modifier allows the function to assign a new value using a reference to another variable. Normally, parameters are "by value", where a copy of the variable's value is passed in.

Note that the second version would be preferred in this case. By reference parameters should only be used when they are truly necessary, not as a replacement for a simple return value.

Comment: The second version is still not idea. Better written as `return a+115` rather than modifying the input parameter.

Answer (score 4):

The question is very hard to decipher. I think that you have tried two different versions of the function that you named `Count`, as shown below.

Consider this version of the function:

```
public int Count1(int a)
{
    a = 115;
    return a;
}
```

It returns 115 no matter what value you pass as the parameter. You are overwriting the parameter with the assignment `a = 115`. The parameter is therefore utterly pointless.

And now the other version:

```
public int Count2(int a)
{
    a = a + 115;
    return a;
}
```

This version of the function receives a parameter in the variable `a`. It then adds on 115 to that value, and returns the result. So when you call it like this:

```
Count2(100)
```

the value that is returned is 215.

It might be easier to understand if you wrote the functions like this:

```
public int Count1(int a)
{
    return 115; //very clearly the input parameter is ignored
}

public int Count2(int a)
{
    return a + 115; //but in this version, the input parameter is used
}
```

These versions are exactly equivalent to your versions but I hope you'll find them easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

a = 115 sets an integer variable to 115, a += 115 or a = a + 115 will add 115 to the value for a and then you are returning the result of that value

Answer (score 1):

if you pass `100` to function which has statement `a = a + 115` which is a = 100 + 115 then it should return 215

```
public int Count(int a)
{
    a = a + 115; // a = 100 + 115 
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do `a=115`, it displays `115` because you're ASSIGNING `115` to `a`.  When you use the `=`, you're ASSIGNING the right value to the left value.  Much the same you're doing when you do `int c=100`.  You're assigning `c` to be `100`.

When you pass in `c`, `c` is `100`, and your formula is `a=a+115`, then `a` will be `215`.  When you pass in a value like you're doing, `a` will be `100`.  So, when you do your formula of `a=a+115`, you're saying `a=100+115`, and you'll get the `215`.

Answer (score 1):

Is the confusion because you think "a" and "c" are separate values?

> The method Count(int a) doesn't care that the name of the value was
>   originally "c". Once it is inside of that method, it will be referred
>   to only as "a."

```
public int Count(int a)
{
    a = a+115;
    return a;
}
```

So step-by-step:

> 1) You pass the value 100 to the Count() method. (a = 100)
>
> 2) Count() sets the value of a to 100 + 115. (a = 215)
>
> 3) 215 is returned back to your calling method.
>
> 4) Your calling method displays 215 as a string.

Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Your `Count()` method just throws away the value it was passed and returns `115`. If you replace `a=115` with `a=a+115`, and pass it `100`, it will return 215. This is all as expected.

`a=a+115` means "take the value of `a`, add 115 to it, and assign the total to `a`."

This is all working as expected.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're wondering how the variable `a` translates to your message box. This is because the variable `a` is in your `count()` function. Changing its value changes the result of the count function. And since your message box gets its value from `count`, there you have it.